# Maven error when trying to build?

Tags: eclipse, maven, java-8

I'm getting this error and I've tried Googling it, but nothing I've been trying seems to work. 
What could this be? (new to Maven)

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building FlarumRegister 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ flarumregistration ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\***\workspace\flarumregistration\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ flarumregistration ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ flarumregistration ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 3 source files to C:\Users\***\workspace\flarumregistration\target\classes
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.320 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-06-09T17:19:28+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/98M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project flarumregistration: Compilation failure -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Comment: It should display you which class is failing for compilation.

Comment: Where would it display that? This is all that displays without the -e switch.

Comment: It should display something like `[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) on project Sample: Compilation failure
[ERROR] D:\KK\HSCIC\MediPi\Workspace\Sample\src\main\java\com\shape\TestShape.java:[24,28] error: static interface methods are not supported in -source 1.5 [ERROR] -> [Help 1]`

Comment: use -e -X, and use the current maven compiler plugin, and enable its verbosity options

Comment: The errors says 'error: static interface methods are not supported in -source 1.5', maven is falling back to 1.5 as minimum version, so what version of Java are you using?

Comment: @gtonic That is just an example I have provided.

Comment: ah. misleading. I'll delete my post. Please revert the downvote. Why would you post something specific like this anyways?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/dejupoyohi.log - I would personally rather first go without the -X and see if the issue can be figured out from here. Also, I fixed the version.

Comment: Well it took a bit, but when I woke up today I somehow fixed it. Don't ask me how. Thanks for the help ayways :)